# Proof of random work property given the absolute value of variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

> This hints that $E(|S_n|)\,\!$, the expected translation distance
>   after ''n'' steps, should be of the order of $\sqrt n$. In fact,
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{E(|S_n|)}{\sqrt n}= \sqrt{\frac 2{\pi}}.$$ (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk)

Why is it like this? After looking at Wikipedia contents all below, I was not able to find proof - so can anyone provide me proof?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238031/application-of-central-limit-theorem

Comment: *Random work* is kind of poetry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the arguments in the link in the comment above, there is this possibility to use a relationship between central limit theorems and moment convergence.

If $S_n$ is a sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables satisfying $E X=0$, $E X^2=1$ and more generally $E|X|^r < \infty$ for some $r\geq 2$, then $E|S_n/ \sqrt{n}|^r$ converges to $E |Z|^r $ where $Z$ is a standard normal. (See theorem 5.1 on page 353 in Gut's "[Probabity: a graduate course](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387228330)")

Applying this to $E | S_n/ \sqrt{n}|$ yields $\sqrt{2/\pi}$ because this the expectation of $E |Z| $ for a standard normal.