# Central limit theorem, show that $E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$ converges to $E[|Z|]$

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

This is the exercise 21.9 to the chapter "The Central Limit Theorem" in the book of Jean Jacod and Philip Protter "Probability essentials".

$\mathbf{Exercise:}$ Let $(X_j)_{j\ge1}$ be i.i.d. with $E[X_j]=0$ and $\sigma^2_{X_j}=\sigma^2<\infty$. Let $S_n=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j.$ Show that:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$

$\mathbf{My}$ $\mathbf{attempt:}$ If I understand it right, we need to show that $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $|Z|$, where $Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, and then it is easy to conclude that $E[|Z|]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$, so we would be done. Note that the central limit theorem asserts that $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\to N(0,\sigma^2)$, which already seems to be a bit suspicious. What I've done I tried to rewrite $|S_n|$ as the sum $S_n\mathbf{1}_{S_n\ge0}+S_n\mathbf{1}_{S_n<0}$ and play with the expectation of this sum but it gave me nothing. Then I decided to work with characteristic functions but all my efforts went in vain (I got stuck in finding the char functions both of $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ and of $|Z|$). Though it is not difficult to calculate the density function of $|Z|$.

Any hint on how to proceed in solving of this exercise is desperately welcome!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Comment: "we need to show that $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $|Z|$ ... and then it is easy to conclude that $E[|Z|]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$, so we would be done" Actually, **exactly the opposite holds**: to show that $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ converges in distribution to $|Z|$ and that $E[|Z|]=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$ is direct, but then another argument is needed to deduce that $E[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}]$ converges to $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$.

Comment: @d.k.o. This problem has nothing to do with the continuous mapping theorem. It's all about the uniform integrability.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Sure. The comment was about why $|S_n|\sqrt{n}\xrightarrow{d}|Z|$...

Comment: The function $f(x)=|x|, x\in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, but not bounded, so $f(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})\overset{d}{\to}f(Z)$ is o.k. with the continuous mapping theorem, but $\mathsf{E}[f(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}})]\to\mathsf{E}[f(Z)]$ needs to explanation.

Comment: Please note also, that in the book this exercise is come from there are no preceeding theorems based on uniform integrability which can help to show the expectations convergence. And the definition of u.i. itself appears more pages after this exercise in martingal section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying Central Limit Theorem to show that $E\left(\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \to \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238031/applying-central-limit-theorem-to-show-that-e-left-fracs-n-sqrtn-right)

Answer (score 0):

The part which *is easy to conclude*:

Sure, if the uniform integrability is prevoiusly defined and if convergence of expectations under u.i. condition is proved then it suffices to say that uniform boundedness of second moments of $|S_n|/\sqrt{n}$ implies u.i. But as I can see, we cannot based on u.i. in frame of the book cited. Then let us prove the convergence of expectations directly.

Express the expectation of $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ in the form
$$
\mathbb E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right] = \mathbb E\left[\,f_N\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right] - N\mathbb P\left(\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq N\right)+\mathbb E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}, \frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq N\right] $$
$$ = E_1-E_2+E_3,
$$
where $N>0$ and continuous and bounded function $f$ is given as follows:
$$
f_N(x)=\begin{cases} |x|, & |x|<N, \cr N, & |x|\geq N\end{cases}
$$
By CLT and the definition of weak convergence, $\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{d} Z\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ implies $E_3\to \mathbb E[f_N(Z)]$ as $n\to\infty$ for any $N>0$ since $f_N$ is continuous and bounded function.

Markov inequality $\mathbb P(|X|\geq N)=\mathbb P(X^2\geq N^2)\leq \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{N^2}$ yields
$$
0\leq E_2=N\mathbb P\left(\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq N\right)\leq N\frac{\mathbb E\left[\frac{S_n^2}{n}\right]}{N^2}=\frac{ \text{Var}\left[S_n\right]}{nN}=\frac{\sigma^2}{N} \quad \text{for any }n\geq 1.
$$
And $E_3$ can be uniformly bounded too: 
$$
0\leq E_3=\mathbb E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}},\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq N\right]\leq \mathbb E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\times\underbrace{\frac{\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}}{N}}_{\geq 1},\ \frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\geq N\right]\leq
\frac{\mathbb E\left[\frac{S_n^2}{n}\right]}{N}=\frac{\sigma^2}{N}. 
$$
Since
$$
E_1-E_2\leq E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\leq E_1+E_3
$$
and we bounded uniformly $E_2$ and $E_3$ for any $n$, take limits as $n\to\infty$ for $N$ fixed:
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathbb E[f_N(Z)]-\frac{\sigma^2}{N}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathbb E\left[\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right]\leq \mathbb E[f_N(Z)]+\frac{\sigma^2}{N}
$$

Next allow $N$ tendes to infinity. Repeat the same:
$$
\mathbb E[|Z|]=\mathbb E[f_N(Z)] - N\mathbb P(|Z|\geq N)+\mathbb E\left[|Z|, \ |Z|\geq N\right].
$$
And
$$
\mathbb E[f_N(Z)] \leq \mathbb E[|Z|] + N\mathbb P(|Z|\geq N) \leq \mathbb E[|Z|] + \frac{\sigma^2}{N}
$$
and 
$$
\mathbb E[f_N(Z)]\geq \mathbb E[|Z|] - E\left[|Z|, \ |Z|\geq N\right] \geq 
\mathbb E[|Z|] -\frac{\sigma^2}{N}.$$
So, $\mathbb E[f_N(Z)]\to \mathbb E[|Z|]$ as $N\to\infty$ and limsup and liminf in (\ref{1}) tends to the same limit $\mathbb E[|Z|]$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for help, NCh. But unfortunately I did not understand your solution fully. I used the hint of the course assistant to solve the exercise. He advised to distinguish two different cases: when $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$ is bounded and when it is not bounded. Then apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that the expectation of $\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}$, when it is unbounded, eventually becomes 0.

Comment: @AlekseiN  Could you post your own solution here so everyone can se it?