# Does this sequence of random variables converge almost surely?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I was trying to understand why almost sure convergence doesn't imply convergence of the mean and I encountered this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/533250/336761).

However, I do not understand why this sequence of random variables converges to $0$ almost surely. How is this example different from [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/149777)? For me, both these sequences are working the same way: the probability of them being $0$ is increasing with $n$. So why one of them converges to $0$ almost surely, and the other doesn't?

Comment: If you are referring, for the second, to [Davide Giraudo's anwer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/149786/75808): because the probability to be non-zero $0$ decreases much faster ($1/n^2$) in the first case than in the second ($1/n$). At a very hazy level (that e.g. [Borel—Cantelli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) helps to make precise), we have $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} < \infty$, while $\sum_n \frac{1}{n} = \infty$.

Comment: Also, it would help if you could include the actual sequences of r.v. in your question, to make it self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As for quoting those answers: I didn't know how to include authors' names, so I decided not to do this at all. Sorry if I that made my question harder to read.