# Does $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

If there is a sequence of random variables ${X_n}$ converging almost surely to $X$, therm is it true that $E(X_n)\rightarrow E(X)$ as $n\to\infty$ ? Only thing given is that $E(X_n)\le 23$ for all $n$.

I am not getting how to do it. I can't use DCT here, can I?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does almost sure convergence implies convergence of the mean?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533246/does-almost-sure-convergence-implies-convergence-of-the-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not.

Consider: $$X_n(\omega) = \begin{cases}
        n & \mbox{ if } \omega\in [0,\frac{1}{n}] \\
        0  & \mbox{ otherwise}
         \end{cases}$$

Then $X_n \to X$ where $X \equiv 0$, $E[X_n] = 1 \le 23$, so $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} E[X_n] = 1$ but $E[X] = 0$

Comment: What is $x$... ?

Comment: X is constant 0

Comment: I meant (and I wrote) lowercase $x$ - in the "if".

Comment: I guess now it's clear :-)