# Series Converging Almost Surely But Diverging in Mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expected-value, probability-limit-theorems

I am looking for an example of independent, non-negative random variables $X_1, X_2, \dots$ such that

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \, \lt \, \infty
$$

almost surely but

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_n) \, = \, \infty
$$

---

I can find [examples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533246/does-almost-sure-convergence-implies-convergence-of-the-mean) of sequences which converge almost surely but diverge in mean, but can’t seem to be able to cook up an example with a series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example, take $X_n$ s.t. $P(X_n = 2^n) = \frac{1}{2^n}$, $P(X_n = 0) = 1 - \frac{1}{2^n}$. Then a.s. all but finitely many $X_n$ are zeroes, so $\sum X_n$ converges a.s., but $\mathbb E (X_n) = 1$, so series of mean diverges.

Comment: In your example of transforming a sequence example to a series example (i.e. $X_{n+1} = Y_{n+1} - X_n$), does this not result in random variables, $X_n$, which are not independent?

Comment: Indeed it does. Probably I have missed the independence when thought about it.