# Example of $X_n$ which converge a.s. but not in mean

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, self-learning

> Provide an example of a sequence of random variables which converge a.s. but not in mean.

I know that the random variables $X_n=n\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}$ converge in probability as given any $\varepsilon>0$
\begin{align*}
P(|X_n-0|>\varepsilon)=P(X_n>\varepsilon)\le P(X_n>0)=P\big(\big(0,\frac{1}{n}\big)\big)=\frac{1}{n}\to 0
\end{align*}
However, they do not converge in mean as

\begin{align*}
E|X_n-0|=E\big(n\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(0\frac{1}{n})}\big)=n\cdot P\big(\big(0,\frac{1}{n}\big)\big)=n\cdot\frac{1}{n}=1\,\,\text{for all n}
\end{align*}

So, my question here is do these $X_n$ converge to $0$ a.s.? And if so, how does one show this rigorously with an $\varepsilon$ proof? I know we need to find $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $X_N<\varepsilon$. To this end, we can make the lengths of the intervals $\big(0,\frac{1}{n}\big)$ arbitrarily small but the multiplication by $n$ stops $X_n$ from being arbitrarily small, so I am sort of thinking that these $X_n$ do not converge a.s. If thats the case, whats an example that would work here?

Comment: What is $P((0,\frac1n))$ here? Or rather, what's the underlying probability measure? Uniform on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @cwindolf P is Lebesgue measure here.

Comment: @cwindolf I think he means "the measure of the event $(0, \frac{1}{n})$". Since his universe is $\Omega = (0,1)$, this makes sense.

Comment: @FiMePr Yes, that is exactly what I meant, sorry that wasn't more clear.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533246/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to prove that the event $\lbrace X_n(\omega) \rightarrow 0 \rbrace$ has probability $1$.

I claim that this event is the universe $\Omega$ itself. In fact, for any $\omega \in (0,1)$, the sequence $X_n(\omega)$ eventually vanishes.

Comment: Ahhh, indeed. I was not working with the $\omega$'s properly. So, for any $\omega\in\Omega$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega\notin\big(0,\frac{1}{N}\big)$ and thus $X_n=0<\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$. And so $X_n(\omega)\to 0$ for all $\omega$, thus $P(X_n\to 0)=1$. Is that correct?

Comment: @SpiderBite Exactly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Provide an example of a sequence of random variables which converge a.s. but not in mean.

Consider a random variable $U$ which is uniform in $[0;1]$ and let

$$ X_n=
\begin{cases}
n,  & \text{if $U \leq \frac{1}{n}$ } \\
0, & \text{if $U >\frac{1}{n}$}
\end{cases}$$

We have

$$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} n\mathbb{P}(U\leq\frac{1}{n})=1$$

On the other hand, for any outcome $\omega$ for which $U(\omega)>0$ (which happens with probability 1), $X(\omega)$ converges to zero.

Thus $X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. but $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$ does not.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks for the alternate example!

Comment: Isn't it the same example ?

Answer (score 0):

Payoff in the Gambler's ruin problem with a double until the first win, then stop. If you start with A coins and double the bet every time you lose, assuming you have infinite money, current wealth converges:
$$
X_n(\omega) \to_n X(\omega)=A+1 \text{ wp 1}
$$
So $E \lim X_n = A+1$. At the same time, $\lim_n EX_n = -3 2^{n+1} \frac{1}{2} + 2^{n+1}\frac{1}{2}$