# $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability, but $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ does not converge to $\mathbb{E}(X)$

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

What is an example of a sequence $X_1,X_2,...$ such that $X_n\rightarrow X$ in probability, but $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ does not converge to $\mathbb{E}(X)$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider for instance:
$$
X_n = \begin{cases}
n \text { with probability }\frac 1n\\
0 \text { with probability }1 - \frac 1n\\
\end{cases}
$$

- $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = \frac 1n\to 0$ hence $X_n\to X = 0$ in probability.
- $EX_n = \frac 1n\times n + \left(1-\frac 1n\right)\times 0 = 1
  \to 1 \neq EX$

Comment: But how do i prove that this converges in probability but the expectation doesn't?

Comment: the exprectation isn't a problem... for the convergence, go back to the definition?

Comment: Why isnt the expectation a problem?

Comment: @TonyStrong I edited with more details.