# Does convergence in probability imply convergence in 2-mean for normalized partial sums of nonnegative random variables?

Tags: probability, limits, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2,…$ be nonnegative random variables with partial sums $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\frac{S_n}{E(S_n)}−1|>\varepsilon)=0$ holds for any $\varepsilon>0$ (and thus the sequence $\frac{S_n}{E(S_n)}$ converges in probability to $X=1$), does this imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}E|\frac{S_n}{E(S_n)}−1|^2=0$? If not, can you provide a counter example?

Answer (score 0):

Since 
$$p:=\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}-1\right|>\varepsilon\right)
=\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}-1\right|^2>\varepsilon^2\right)
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}-1\right|^2\right) \le 
(1-p)\varepsilon^2+p\mathbb{E}\left(\left|\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}-1\right|^2\big| \left|\frac{S_n}{\mathbb{E}(S_n)}-1\right|>\varepsilon\right).
$$

Since by your assumption you have that $p\to 0$ if $n\to\infty$, it all depends on whether your sequence of partial sums is [uniformly integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability). See also the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477942/does-convergence-in-probability-implies-convergence-of-the-mean) and the last property of [this section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_4).

Answer (score 0):

A counterexample is given by choosing $X_i$ iid with $E[X_i]<+\infty$ and $E[X_i^2]=+\infty$. The law of large numbers give $S_n/E[S_n]\to 1$ in probability as required, but
$$E[|S_n/E[S_n]-1|^2]=+\infty$$ for all $n$.