# When does distribution convergence imply expectation convergence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $X_n \xrightarrow{d} X$ what are the minimal hypothesis to have $E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X]$ ? For example I think that if all the second moments are bounded it's true, but I'm not sure if is true if the first moments are bounded.

Comment: It's true when $\{X_n\mid n\geq 1\}$ is uniformly integrable, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112786/convergence-in-law-and-uniformly-integrability). In particular it holds when the second moments are bounded.

Comment: But not when only the first moments are bounded.

Comment: Why second moments bounded $\rightarrow$ uniformly integrable ?

Comment: @Febo This follows from Markov's inequality: $$\int_{|X_n|>R} |X_n| \, d\mathbb{P} \leq \frac{1}{R} \int X_n^2 \, d\mathbb{P}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable and $X_n\xrightarrow{d}X$ then $E[X_n]\rightarrow E[X]$ ( See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112786/convergence-in-law-and-uniformly-integrability) ).

Now if $\exists\ M>0\ $ and $\ \exists\ p>0$ s.t.  $E[|X_n|^p]<M$,  $\ \  (X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly integrable by Markov inequality: $$R^{p-1}\int_{|X_n|>R} |X_n| \, d\mathbb{P} \leq  \int |X_n|^p \, d\mathbb{P}\leq M.$$

If the first moment is bounded this is not true, in fact if you take $X_n:=n\mathbb{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$, $X:=0$ in $((0,1),\mathcal B, \mathbb P)$, with $\mathbb P$ the Lebesgue measure, you have a counterexample. The first moments are constantly $1$, but the expectations don't converge to $0$.