# Root-$n$ consistency of an estimator implies its variance is $O(n^{-1})$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, proof-writing, asymptotics

(This is from a claim on page 20 of Hall's 1992 The Bootstrap and the Edgeworth Expansion.)

Suppose we observe i.i.d. data $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from some unknown CDF $F$. Let $\theta_0=\theta(F)$ be a parameter that can be computed from the CDF and $\hat\theta$ an estimator.

Hall then mentions: "should $\hat\theta$ be $\sqrt{n}$-consistent for $\theta_0$, so that $E(\hat\theta-\theta_0)^2=O(n^{-1})$ ..."

> Why is this true?

Could you please in particular provide a **rigorous** argument (you can make further assumptions if necessary)? My interest in this study is to see how such an argument can be constructed.

My progress so far is that I understand the claim intuitively, as follows: the $\sqrt{n}$-consistency of $\hat\theta$ means there is some fixed positive number $V$ such that
$$
\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta-\theta_0)\approx N(0,V)\implies E[(\hat\theta-\theta_0)^2]\approx\frac{1}{n}V=O(n^{-1}).
$$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun I agree to your suggestion. I will edit within 20 minutes or so.

Answer (score 1):

By the continuous mapping theorem, $n(\hat \theta-\theta_0)^2 \xrightarrow{\mathcal L} \mathcal N(0,1)^2 $.

If $n(\hat \theta-\theta_0)^2$ is uniformly integrable [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112786/convergence-in-law-and-uniformly-integrability)  $E(n(\hat \theta-\theta_0)^2) \to 1$ and the bound easily follows.

I'm not sure there's much you can say without the uniform integrability assumption. The weak Fatou's lemma yields $1\leq \liminf_n E(n(\hat \theta-\theta_0)^2)$.