# Convergence in distribution implies point-wise convergence of MGF

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence, moment-generating-functions

Let $\mu_n, \mu$ be probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mu_n$ converges in distribution to $\mu$. Let $M_n(s) = \mathbb{E}(e^{sX_n})$ and $M(s) = \mathbb{E}(e^{sX})$ be the respective moment generating functions. Assume that $M_n(s)$ is finite in a common interval $[-s_0, s_0]$, $s_0 > 0$. Does it follow that $M_n(s) \rightarrow M(s)$ in this interval?

I want to know if this holds in order to prove a version of the continuity theorem for MGFs. The issue I am having is that the function $e^{sx}$ is continuous but not bounded, unlike the case for characteristic functions.

Comment: My guess is, yes on $(-s_0,s_0)$ but not  in general on $[-s_0,s_0]$.

Comment: @kimchilover any thoughts on why that may be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If uniform integrability of $\{\exp\left(sX_n\right),n\geqslant 1\}$ takes place, then usingthe fact that uniform integrability and convergence in distribution [implies convergence of the expectations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112786/convergence-in-law-and-uniformly-integrability).

This holds if we assume that for all $s\in (-s_0.s_0)$, $\sup_{n\geqslant 1}\mathbb E\left[\exp\left(sX_n\right)\right]$ is finite.

However, the convergence may not hold at $s_0$. For example, if $s_0=1$, take a sequence of positive random variables $(Y_n)$ which converges in distribution say to one and such that $\mathbb EY_n$ does not converge to one ($Y_n=n^2$ and $1$ with respective probabilitites $1/n$ and $1-1/n$) and let $X_n=\ln(Y_n)$.
In this example, $M_n(s)$ is finite for all $s$ but converges only for $s\leqslant 0$.

Comment: Thanks @Davide, but why does it hold that $\exp(sX_n)$ is uniformly integrable for $s \in (-s_0, s_0)$?

Comment: @NikhilGhosh Actually, it seems that uniform integrability may not hold without further assumptions.

Comment: Ok I think I see now. Uniform integrability now follows from the fact that $\mathbb{E}(\exp(sX_n) ; \exp(sX_n) \geq \alpha) \leq \frac{1}{\alpha^{\delta}} \int \exp(s(1+\delta)X_n) dP$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo For the counterexample given, does it show that the continuity theorem does not hold for moment generating function? But the tricky thing is I believe I have seen the continuity of MGF several times...