# Weakest condition for convergence in expectation

Tags: probability

Because of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112786/convergence-in-law-and-uniformly-integrability), we know that weak convergence plus uniform integrability implies convergence in expectation. But can one prove that if we have weak convergence and convergence in expectation of  non-negative RVs, then we must have uniform integrability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $X_n=n1_{(0,\frac 1  n)} -n1_{(-\frac 1  n,0)} $ and $0$. Then, $X_n \to X$ a.s., hence in distribution.  Also, $EX_n=0=EX$ for all $n$. But $(X_n)$ is not uniformly integrable since $\int_{X_n \geq n} X_ndP \geq 1$.

For nonnegaive r.v.'s the answer is in the affirmative. This can be proved using two theorems: 1) Skhorohod Theorem 2) Sheffe's Lemma. By the first theorem we may replave convergence in distrbution by a.s. convergence. Then second theorem  implies that $E|X_n-X| \to 0$ which implies uniform integrability.

Comment: Good counterexample, but see my edit for a missing condition, the $X_i$ must be $\geq 0$

Comment: It is not good to change questions after answers have appeared but I have anyway answered your new question also. @Eulerian